# Crash firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crash, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an app with Swift and Firestore and since yesterday evening, my app crash when it start on when executing  :

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Here is the error message :

> 2018-05-23 10:27:08.562176+0200 protoMeteoApp[51741:3501027] 4.9.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40009000 started
>
> 2018-05-23 10:27:08.578312+0200 protoMeteoApp[51741:3501027] 4.9.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3ec8a1cb4)
>
> 2018-05-23 10:27:08.592866+0200 protoMeteoApp[51741:3500914] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]'

**First throw call stack:**

```
(
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010925f1e6 
__exceptionPreprocess + 294

...... 

)
```

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I tried to fix it creating a new project, downloading again "GoogleService-Info.plist" but it still crash.

Any idea ?

Comment: Try updating Pods

Comment: Already done. I cleaned my project, updated Pods but still broken

Comment: At the end of that log, it says "attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]", which indicates it's not a the issue you think it is. You may want to go into the class that is being loaded first and add breakpoints to see where it's attempting to add an object to that dictionary when it's nil. Hope this helps.

Comment: I used breakpoint and it crashes executing "FirebaseApp.configure()". So I guess it's a problem with the configuration of Firestore but I don't know where does it come from.

Answer (score 0):

- Can add following two keys into your `Info.plist` file:

  1. Set `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to `YES`
  2. Set `FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled` to `NO`
- Also configure your **Firebase app** into **AppDelegate.swift** file inside **`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`** method before use of Firebase as: 
  **`FirebaseApp.configure()`**